# Mysql select query can't able to search symbolic string

Tags: mysql

For example if I want to search below.

```
> lav'ro (I can't search it by "lav'r" because of ' in the string)     
> am[op]st (I can't search it by "am[o" because of [ in the string)
```

My question is how can I use select query so I will help me to bring output?

Below are my SELECT query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE (Col1 LIKE '%$value%' OR Col2 LIKE '%$value%') 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN (Col1 LIKE '$value' AND Col2 LIKE '$value') THEN 1 
         WHEN Col1 LIKE '$value' THEN 2 
         WHEN Col2 LIKE '$value' THEN 3 
         WHEN Col1 LIKE '$value%' THEN 4 
         WHEN Col2 LIKE '$value%' THEN 5 
         WHEN Col1 LIKE '%$value' THEN 6 
         WHEN Col2 LIKE '%$value' THEN 7 
         WHEN Col1 LIKE '%$value%' THEN 8 
         WHEN Col2 LIKE '%$value%' THEN 9 
         ELSE 10 
    END asc, 
    length(Col1 or Col2) limit 15
```

Here **"$value"** dynamic word for search.

It's working well In normal search, problem with symbolic search.

Comment: In sql you need to escape quotes and other character with a backslash. However when using this sql statement in any programming language, you might want to look into prepared statements.

Comment: @Webber sorry for wrong tag, I just removed it. I'm using "mysql"

Comment: Don't worry, mysql is just a dialect of sql so it wasn't incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include \ before the single quote to make it work

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE 'lav\'ro'
```

For the 2nd issue try % to append before or after or both

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%am[o%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `like`.  You can just use `instr()` or `=`:

```
where instr(col1, ?) > 0
```

Use `like` and regular expressions when you need them for their pattern matching capabilities.

And -- for the record -- there is no problem searching for single quotes in a string.  The only problem is expressing the string.  To do this, double up on the single quote:

```
where col1 like concat(?, '%')
```

works when you pass a parameter with a single quote.  This also works:

```
where col1 like 'lav''r%'
```

Comment: Is it work with mysql too? Sorry I for wrong tagged with question. I just removed it. Btw I'm using mysql db I have multiple cases as you can see in my query but let me check. Thank you.

Comment: @Govaadiyo . . . Of course these work in MySQL.  Here is an example:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80d33fbde3df86dd9b28c90b8330d6c2.